# Thymeleaf, how to do a new paragraph with a string of text

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my Java program, I have a populator with a string that is 2 paragraphs long.

```
String myString = "Paragraph 1 text... \n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "Paragraph 2 text...";
```

When I display it using Thymeleaf, it displays as 1 paragraph.

```
"Paragraph 1 text... Paragraph 2 text..."
```

How do I separate them into paragraphs like so:

```
"Paragraph 1 text...

Paragraph 2 text..."
```

Here's the Thymeleaf to display the text:

```
        <section class="post-content" th:text="${post.myString}">
        </section>
```

EDIT:
I have tried using tags (like `<p>` and `<br />`) but they get displayed as text and not as html tags.

Comment: Look up the difference between `text` and `utext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `<br>` tag to create a line break to display on the front end, instead of `"\n"`.

```
String myString = "Paragraph 1 text... <br/>" +
                    "<br/>" +
                    "Paragraph 2 text...";
```

You can use [`th:utext`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text) to display the HTML without escaping.

```
<section class="post-content" th:utext="${post.myString}">
</section>
```

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried. All tags are displayed in the text:

```Paragraph 1 text ...<br />``` That's how it displays using thymeleaf

Comment: @jrob11 Could you show how you are displaying the string?

Answer (score 1):

You can of course insert html and use `th:utext`.

```
// Java
String myString = "Paragraph 1 text... <br /><br />Paragraph 2 text...";

<!-- HTML -->
<section class="post-content" th:utext="${post.myString}" />
```

(When possible, I would avoid this because it's more open to abuse -- the html in this variable could cause your page to display incorrectly, or there could be scripts injected -- I would never use `th:utext` with untrusted user input for example.)

You can also choose to display newlines with css.  For example:

```
// Java
String myString = "Paragraph 1 text... \n\nParagraph 2 text...";

<!-- HTML -->
<section class="post-content" style="white-space: pre-line;" th:text="${post.myString}" />
```